# salesforce lightning $A.get("e.force:createRecord") return empty

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript, softphone

I tried  component to open the new contact page. [Complete reference code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm)

```
var createAcountContactEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
createAcountContactEvent.setParams({
      "entityApiName": "lead",
      "defaultFieldValues": {
            'Phone' : '415-240-6590',
            'Mobile' : '001xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
       }
});
createAcountContactEvent.fire();
```

`$A.get("e.force:createRecord")` // Does not trigger page

I tried in softphone. How can i solve the issue?

and also i tried `sforce.one.createRecord()` its also doesn't work.
`one` property doesn't available in `sforce` object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [screenPop() for Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_screenpop_lex.htm).

Example:

```
sforce.opencti.screenPop({
     type: sforce.opencti.SCREENPOP_TYPE.*, //Review the arguments section.
     params: object //Depends on the SCREENPOP_TYPE. Review the arguments section.
} 
});
```